# Puppeteer: Replacing innerHTML inside the same selectors

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

When taking screenshots using **puppeteer**, dynamic elements with the `.menu__link` class are required to change innerHTML to a stub.

I use **BackstopJs** `puppet/onReady.js`

When I try this, only the first element on the page is replaced:

```js
module.exports = async (page) => {
    const myLocalValue = "Test";
    const tweets = await page.$$('.menu__link');


    for (const tweet of tweets) {
        await page.$eval('.menu__link', (el, value) => el.innerHTML = value, myLocalValue)
    }
};
```

And this code does not work at all:

```js
module.exports = async (page) => {
    const myLocalValue = "Test";
    const tweets = await page.$$('.menu__link');


    for (const tweet of tweets) {
        await page.$eval(tweet, (el, value) => el.innerHTML = value, myLocalValue)
    }
};
```

Please tell me how to replace **innerHTML** on the entire page for all `.menu__link` using puppeteer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$$eval](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args)

```
await page.$$eval('. menu__link', (links, value) => links.forEach(el => el.innerHTML = value), 'myLocalValue');
```

Comment: Sir, I am very grateful to you. Its working nice pretty.